# Chromatic Number of a graph obtained from Petersen’s graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I am studying on Chromatic numbers of graphs and I came across Petersen’s graph.

[image: Petersen graph 3-coloring]

**Petersen’s graph** which is an undirected graph with 10 vertices and 15 edges. And it has the chromatic number 3, meaning that its vertices can be colored with three colors — but not with two — such that no edge connects vertices of the same color.

**The Question is** Let G be obtained from Petersen’s graph by adding no more than three
edges. What can the chromatic number of such graph be? List all the possible values.

**MY ATTEMPT:** From Brooks theorem if G is connected $\chi(G) = \Delta (G) $ unless $G$ is complete or an odd cycle, in which case the $\chi (G) = \Delta (G) = 1 $

So for **Case 1:** (If I add an additional edge) my $|E| = 16$ edges and $|V|=$ 12 vertices (still an even cycle) i.e $\chi (G) = 3$ still.

For **Case 2**: (add two edges) 17 edges and 14 vertices (even cycle) $\chi (G) = 3$ still. and likewise for **Case 3** $\chi (G) = 3$

**Please is my solution correct? Thanks in Advance**

Comment: To get help with this question you need to [edit] the question to include your thoughts on how to tackle the problem, and to tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Are you adding vertices when you also add edges? I don't think that's what the question wanted.

Comment: Dear @MishaLavrov I thought the vertices will also increase simultaneously with the increment in the edges. Please help me out with the right approach. Thanks!

Comment: No, adding edges should not increase vertices. Here's one of many ways you could add $3$ edges to the graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InqOp.png We have gone from $15$ to $18$ edges, but the number of vertices remains at $10$ (count them).

Comment: Oh I see it now @MishaLavrov Thanks!